# Can't modify HTMLElement style

Tags: javascript, html, zooming, mouseover

I'm having an issue with an event listener, using html and scripts.

I'm trying to implements a zoom on a mouse over event, by adding an event listener to my image. I'd like the user to be able to zoom on the image just by passing his pointer over. I found a tuto on yt and tried to replicate it but it doesn't work.

Here's a fiddle :

https://jsfiddle.net/emk16y7u/5/

everything is working correctly, except on the last line when the assignation doesn't seems to work :

```
magnifying_area.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {

    clientX = event.clientX - magnifying_area.offsetLeft
    clientY = event.clientY - magnifying_area.offsetTop

    mWidth = magnifying_area.offsetWidth
    mHeight = magnifying_area.offsetHeight

    clientX = clientX / mWidth * 100
    clientY = clientY / mHeight * 100

    magnifying_img.style.transform = 'translate(-' + clientX + '%, -' + clientY + '%) scale (2)'
});
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: I don't think you need an event listener. `:hover ` would work too. Is that OK?

Comment: @Taplar That  is incorrect.  Just remove the space between scale and (2): `magnifying_img.style.transform = 'translate(-' + clientX + '%, -' + clientY + '%) scale(2)'` and it should  work.

Comment: @ptothep It's always the smallest thing. Thanks al lot !

Answer (score 1):

I think the space is not allowed between the scale the braces. Also you missed some ; on your code. Try this fixed code:

```
magnifying_area.addEventListener("mousemove", function (event) {
    clientX = event.clientX - magnifying_area.offsetLeft;
    clientY = event.clientY - magnifying_area.offsetTop;
    mWidth = magnifying_area.offsetWidth;
    mHeight = magnifying_area.offsetHeight;
    clientX = clientX / mWidth * 100;
    clientY = clientY / mHeight * 100;
    magnifying_img.style.transform = 'translate(-' + clientX + '%, -' + clientY + '%) scale(2)';
});
```